Why do certain verbs lack the expected preposition "with"?
I've noticed an interesting phenomenon in English verb usage that seems counterintuitive to me. Specifically, certain verbs like "marry" and "fight" tend not to use the preposition "with," even though it seems logically fitting given the dynamics of their actions.
For instance, "marry someone" appears to omit "with," despite marriage inherently involving two parties. Similarly, "fight someone" suggests a one-sided action rather than the mutual interaction that a fight implies. In other languages I'm familiar with, these verbs typically include a preposition similar to "with" to denote the reciprocal nature of these actions.
Several other verbs follow this pattern:

Discuss: We "discuss a topic" rather than "discuss with a person," despite the mutual exchange implied.

Contact: We often say "contact someone" instead of "contact with someone," even though the act implies two-way communication.


Could someone provide insights on this phenomenon? Is there a specific term for this kind of verb construction where the expected preposition is omitted? Additionally, what historical or linguistic rationale might explain this pattern in English, setting it apart from other languages?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
